# Unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement" when trying to run an npm library

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm

I am trying to install the PhotoEditor SDK library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/photoeditorsdk) in my Ruby on Rails project by following the installation instructions provided in the official documentation (https://img.ly/docs/pesdk/web/guides/rails/). However, I am encountering an error in the DOM console that reads:

"Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: /Users/robeen/dev/cocoon-immo/node_modules/photoeditorsdk/esm/chunk-2FC7YEBB.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement""

I have already followed all the installation steps listed in the documentation, including installing the necessary peer dependencies (React, React DOM, and Styled Components) etc...

Despite following all the steps correctly, I am still encountering the error mentioned above. I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

```
Dev environment :

 - Node : v14.15.5
 - Ruby : ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]
 - Rails : Rails 6.1.7.3
 - NPM : 8.11.0
```

Comment: This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1269) might be related. It is generally recommended to run supported LTS versions of Node.js. v14 has reached its end of life (in 2021) and v18 is currently the LTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An internet search for `Unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"` turns up a lot of discussion about Babel and re-enabling IE11 support.

Try Updating your .browserlistrc file to include support for IE11.

It might look like this afterward:

```
defaults
IE 11
```

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention, I searched through all of Google... I've tried pretty much everything that was mentioned. Tried your solution as well... Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Well... I just tried again and it actually worked this time. Thanks.

Comment: It may have been that you needed to restart your server/webpacker to pick up the change.

Answer (score 0):

Our current suggestion would be to use the VanillaJS approach and either use the scripts from a CDN or the vendor folder instead of the NPM packages.
e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IntegrateWithRails</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@4.4.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.img.ly/packages/imgly/photoeditorsdk/latest/umd/no-polyfills.js"></script>
  
  </head>

  <body>
      <%= yield %>
      <div id="editor" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
      <script>
        PhotoEditorSDK.PhotoEditorSDKUI.init({
          container: '#editor',
          // Please replace this with your license: https://img.ly/dashboard
          license: '',
          image:
            'https://cdn.img.ly/packages/imgly/photoeditorsdk/latest/assets/example.jpg',
          assetBaseUrl:
            'https://cdn.img.ly/packages/imgly/photoeditorsdk/latest/assets',
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello IMG.LY team. I appreciate your response. Regrettably, the suggested solution isn't practical for our situation. The VanillaJS method is leading to the identical problem, and the use of the CDN method isn't a suitable option for us since we prefer to asynchronously invoke this library when required. Could you kindly confirm if this problem originates from the IMG.LY library itself or if it's a result of some other factor? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The rails application loads your javascript using a gem like https://github.com/rails/webpacker/

It is the configuration that is being used by webpacker and passed to babel that's causing the issue.

Like @tgf said, this should have been configurable by .browserslistrc, but the [v6 upgrade migration guide of webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/632fb85d6dab874f381b3b4059bba883c5520a46/docs/v6_upgrade.md) says:

> Copy over custom browserlist config from .browserslistrc if it exists into the "browserslist" key in package.json and remove .browserslistrc.

So, try changing your package.json to include

```json
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "IE11"
  ]
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered 6.  AFAIK it was never officially released.  Rubygems indicates it made it to RC in 2021.  At this point I think the recommended upgrade path for anyone on webpacker 5 is either Shakapacker or jsbundling-rails.